# How to pull the ID (or other attributes) from a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I'm using the bootstrap plugin (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) and the event handler will give me tons of info - lot more than I need.

```
$('.make-switch').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
    var $el = $(data.el)
    , value = data.value;
    console.log(e);
    console.log($el);
    console.log(value);
});
```

I just need the ID of the switch that has been switched as well as the state it is in.  In Firefox firebug, I see in the console window, the following:

`+ Object[input#checkbox_1]`.  When I drill down into the Object, I see a `0` so I click on that which expands further.  Under the `0` I see the ID attribute and corresponding value I'm looking for but I don't know how to reference it.  If I can get some help with this, getting the value will be the same method.

**So my question is, how do I get the ID of the switch that has been thrown?**

I tried using another SO question/answer and adapting it to this problem but it didn't work for me.  I took this:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

and adapted it to this:

```
$('.make-switch').on('switch-change', function (e, data, event) {
    var $el = $(data.el)
    , value = data.value;
    console.log(e);
    console.log($el);
    console.log(value);
            console.log(event.target.id); //but this produces an error
});
```

but the console.log(event.target.id) produces an error.

**So my question is, how do I get the ID of the switch that has been thrown? (in case the question was missed above**

Per a comment:  here is a jsFiddle of what I started off with:
    `http://jsfiddle.net/zZWLx/1/`

Comment: The argument `e` contains what you're looking for when trying `event`

Comment: @ChrisRockwell What is the syntax to access the id of the argument `e`?

Comment: Looking at your other comments, you need something else.  Can you post the HTML, or a fiddle?

Comment: UPDATED:  jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/zZWLx/1/

Comment: Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/zZWLx/3/ (Might be helpful to add link to fiddle in your original post)

Comment: Add your relevant (minimal) HTML to your question, and, if you're able, post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see where it fails.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Where are my mannagers.  Thank you for your help!  I like your solution too in that your provided js variables which I can then use to pass to my ajax call to change the element's status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, inside the handler:

```
console.log($(e.target).attr("id"))
```

EDIT:

Try this, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zZWLx/2/

code:

```
$(".make-switch").on('switch-change', function(event){
    console.log($(event.target).find("input").attr("id"));
})
```

Comment: @dlackey And if you do console.log($(e.target)) ?

Comment: `+Object[div.make-switch]`

Comment: @dlackey it looks like .make-switch doesn't have an id set. Are you trying to get the id of .make-switch, or of something else?

Comment: The switch itself is wrapped in a div tag `<div class='make-switch'>`.  It does not have an id on it.  The id and value of the actual switch is what I'm looking for.  But I think I see where you are heading.

Comment: @dlackey ok, try this: console.log($(e.srcElement).attr("id"))

Comment: still getting `undefined`.  Let me see if I can create a jsfiddle.  I'm not very good at setting those things up though.  :`(

Comment: UPDATED:  Here is the jsfiddle.  Hopefully I did it right.  http://jsfiddle.net/zZWLx/1/

Comment: That'll work.  I was hoping for a more direct approach than using find but it'll work.  Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

If You are using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: In my post, I stated I tried that solution and it did not work but thank you.